# How to bring output of multiple select statement in different columns with row more than 1 in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

i have below select statement which i am trying to run in MYSQL. There are many rows in the output, approx 80.
what i want to achive is , that all the four result come on one screen, in single execution and form 4 columns.

```
select `name` newname1 from table
select `name` newname2 from table2
select `name` newname3 from table3
select `name` newname4 from table4
```

I tried a lot looking in stack overflow, but i dint find relevant.
it work for me if i limit the sub query to 1

```
SELECT (select name newname1 from table1 limit 1 ) as table1 ,
(select name  from newname2 from table 2 limit 1) as table2
```

Data look like below

```
table 1   
========
NAME
========
text
sms
mobile
tv
phone

table 2
========
NAME
========
something
test
road
board

table 3
========
NAME
========
landline
fixedline
elife
```

should be like

```
NAME      NAME      NAME
======   =======    ======
Text     something   landine
sms      test        fixedline
mobile   road        elife
tv       board     
phone
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  To help others help you, you should read this: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reporducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/3399890) and the [edit] your question.

Comment: If I find 'John' and ' Mary' in table1 and 'Mike' and 'Jane' in table2, which pairs shall be shown in the result rows? John-Mike? John-Jane? Mary-Mike? Mary-Jane? All these four combinations? Please tell us which rule you want to apply here.

Comment: By the way: Can you explain why the names are in different tables and why you want them shown in one result, though?

Answer (score 1):

Just use [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html)

```
select `name` newname1 from table
UNION
select `name` newname2 from table2
UNION
select `name` newname3 from table3
UNION
select `name` newname4 from table4
```

The only point is that it will trow an error since you are using 4 different alias for the name field. You should remove the alias or assign to each the same alias

UPDATE: since OP wants to see the data in different columns.

```
select `name` newname1, '' newname2, '' newname3, '' newname4 from table
UNION
select '' newname1, `name` newname2,'' newname3, '' newname4 from table2
UNION
select '' newname1,'' newname2,`name` newname3, '' newname4 from table3
UNION
select '' newname1,'' newname2, '' newname3,`name` newname4 from table4
```

Will do the job

Comment: UNION will not help me, as i want to see data in different column. UNION will give me all in one row.

Comment: with the updated query you will see the data in four different columns. _UNION will give me all in one row_ wrong. You will get as many rows as the sum of results from each single query

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but i am seeing null values in 2nd column aganist the first column.is there a way we can remove those null and big data parallel to each other. it will reduce the row size. other wise this way my rows count will go to 800 instead of 80 for 10 tables

Comment: that's exactly how it works. Each time you change the table you change the column. If you want to see something instead of blank just change what is inside the '' part

Comment: _is there a way we can remove those null and big data parallel to each other_ this must be handled on the presentation layer

Comment: thanks for your response. is there a way that i can create a table on top of these Statements and then remove the null values from tables to make it presentable? just a thought

Comment: @wasim mir: Please edit your request and show sample data (one to three rows per table) and the expected result, so we understand what you are after.

Comment: Below is the data, i have three table, all i want is that data of all the three different table should come in single execution in three column, i got the out put but the union mentioned by @LelioFaieta but there is null coming in second and third column . i do not want that

table 1   
========
NAME
========
text
sms
mobile
tv
phone

table 2
========
NAME
========
something
test
road
board

table 3
========
NAME
========
landline
fixedline
elife

Comment: @wasim mir: No. Edit your request to get this readable. And please show the expected result. And answer the questions in the comments to your request.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I have updated my request, please let me know if looks clear

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are randomly building pairs. Why is it `Text-something-landine` in one row and not, say, `Text-test-elife`? It seems you don't care at all. You just want to show three tables with no order at all side by side (in three columns).

The best way to do this is to run three separate queries and have your app or Website put the results in the three columns.

If you want to do this in SQL, you'll have to join the rows on some generated row number (usually done with `ROW_NUMBER` and `FULL OUTER JOIN`). MySQL features `ROW_NUMBER` as of version 8 and no `FULL OUTER JOIN` so far. This means you would even have to mimic the full outer join. Numbering all rows requires sorting the three datasets first. Then the same numbers must be found in the three data sets for the joins. **All in all a lot of unnecessary work for the DBMS**.

My recommendation: **Don't do this in SQL!**